# Output of mysql2sqlite.sh not compatible with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, mysql

I am using [mysql2sqlite.sh](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776) to convert MySQL dump file to SQLite using PHP. Here is my code:

```
exec('./mysql2sqlite.sh --databases test --host=x.com -u x -ptest | sqlite3 database.sqlite');
```

I dont know if it is right, but the `database.sqlite` output file contains the next wierd characters:

SQLite format 3^@^D^@^A^A^@@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^G^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^E^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@-�^B
^C�^@^F^@�^@^B^P^C�^A�^Am^A^Q^@�^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@N^F^F^W%^W^Aoindexusers_branchusers^GCREATE INDEX "users_branch" ON "users" ("branch")Z^E^F^$
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL ,
  "first_name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "last_name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "password" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  "email" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  "cel" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  "level" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "deleted" int(1) NOT NULL,
  "created" date NOT NULL,
  "modified" timestamp NOT NULL ,
  "company_id" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "branch" int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
))^B^F^W=^W^A^@indexsqlite_autoindex_users_1users^C^@^@^@^D

I tried to add this file to my WPF project with a sqlite database

```
string lines = "";
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(databaseFile))
    {
        lines += sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}

SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db");
conn.Open();

var command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = lines;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

The problem is that i am getting:

> Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database
>
> near "SQLite": syntax error

Also, if i remove the:

> SQLite

Word from the file, the operation does nothing.

Why is the file not getting accepted by WPF? If i use the file on [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) it works perfect.

Comment: The .sqlite file **IS** the database...use the database.sqlite file in your connection string directly instead of test.db

Comment: are the wierd characters fine?

Comment: Ok, you got a point, thank you

Comment: What about if i create a dump file with only rows? How would i be able to insert them in to the database if i cant insert this one